# grunt bowercopy task not found

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, bower

I can't figure out my configuration problem.  When I try to run 'grunt bowercopy', I get this error message:

Warning: Task "bowercopy" not found. Use --force to continue.

If I run 'grunt jshint', jshint works fine.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
     "name": "treblebull",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "express": "~3.2.6",
        "jade": "~0.31.2",
        "underscore": "~1.5.2",
        "pg": "~2.11.1"
      },  
      "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "~0.4.2",
        "grunt-bowercopy": "~0.7.1",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.8.0",
        "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.1"
      }
    }
```

and here is my gruntfile:

```
    'use strict';

    module.exports = function(grunt) {

      grunt.initConfig({
        jshint: {
          options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
          },  
          gruntfile: {
            src: 'Gruntfile.js'
          },  
          lib: {
            src: ['lib/**/*.js']
          },  
          test: {
            src: ['test/**/*.js']
          }   
        },  
        bowercopy: {
          options: {
            clean: true
            //srcPrefix: 'bower_components'
          },  
          libs: {
            options: {
             // destPrefix: 'public/js/lib'
            },  
            files: {
              'angular.js': 'angular/angular.js'
              //'underscore.js': 'underscore/underscore.js',
              //'underscore.string.js': 'underscore.string/underscore.string.js'
            }   
          }   
        }   
      }); 

      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bowercopy');
      grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

    };
```

Comment: Does your Gruntfile have `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-bowercopy');` in it somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is at the bottom of the gruntfile, i guess the code is just a bit too long so you have to scroll inside the gruntfile to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `bower init` to give yourself a bower.json file for the `bowercopy` task to read. Also if you already have installed everything via bower, set `runBower` to `false` in your `options` hash.

If you're ever having Grunt failures, it's worth running with the `--v` (verbose) flag to see exactly what it's failing on. Running this myself I saw it looking for a `bower.json`, and once I supplied one the task succeeded.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared everything up.  --v flag is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing task registration, You need to register a task that you want to explicity run in grunt, so you need this

```
grunt.registerTask('bowercopy', ['bowercopy']);
```

Then you can run

```
grunt bowercopy
```

Comment: i tried both of those, in both cases, jshint works but bowercopy doesn't.  if you scroll to the bottom of the gruntfile in my question you can see the registration task.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment on @dcodesmith's answer due to points, I have to leave an answer. I ran into the problem in that actually adding `grunt.registerTask('bowercopy', ['bowercopy']);`
called bowercopy's task, but it doesn't actually work. Removing it actually allowed bowercopy to copy files.